# Conditional Formatting in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am tying to manage duplicates on an Excel sheet by having the duplicate cells turn red. I put this in a use to sheet protection to keep from editing the conditional formatting for these columns. However, when I move the cell information (by clicking and dragging) the conditional formatting moves from that cell as well. At the end of the day, I do not have duplicate coverage for every cell that I want. Is there some way I can prevent this from happening when I move the cell, or what macro can I put in to take care of this?

I want to do something like this using VBA:

```
Sub Duplicate()
Dim rngData As Range
Dim cell As Range

Set rngData = Range("P3:P19, P56:P58, P39:P42, P21:P25, P27:P37, P39:P42, P39:P42, P44:P54, M25:M76, B69:B77, B66:E67, B51:B64, H44:H47, D44:D47, H42, H33:H40, D33:D42, H31, D28:D31, H28:H29, D5:D8" & Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row)
For Each cell In rngData
cell.Offset(0, 0).Font.Color = vbBlack          ' DEFAULT COLOR
' LOCATE DUPLICATE VALUE(S) IN THE SPECIFIED RANGE OF DATA.
        If Application.Evaluate("COUNTIF(" & rngData.Address & "," & cell.Address & ")") > 1 Then
            cell.Offset(0, 0).Font.Color = vbRed        ' CHANGE FONT COLOR TO RED.
        End If
    Next cell

    Set rngData = Nothing

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

But I get a "Type Mismatch" error at:
If Application.Evaluate("COUNTIF(" & rngData.Address & "," & cell.Address & ")") > 1 Then

How can I get around this?

Comment: The issue is you cannot use a disjointed range in Countif().  So you need to set the rngdata part to the extents as in this case `B3:P81`.

Comment: there are some other items in that region that are duplicates that I do not want highlighted... how else can I get around this?

Comment: Yes you can set a double loop through the data testing whether it is equal or not,and not use the countif.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per comment you would need to loop twice:

```
Sub Duplicate()
Dim rngData As Range
Dim cell As Range
Dim cell2 As Range

Set rngData = Range("P3:P19, P56:P58, P39:P42, P21:P25, P27:P37, P39:P42, P39:P42, P44:P54, M25:M76, B69:B77, B66:E67, B51:B64, H44:H47, D44:D47, H42, H33:H40, D33:D42, H31, D28:D31, H28:H29, D5:D8" & Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row)

rngData.Font.Color = vbBlack

For Each cell In rngData
    If cell.Font.Color = vbBlack Then
        For Each cell2 In rngData
            If cell = cell2 And cell.Address <> cell2.Address Then
                cell.Font.Color = vbRed
                cell2.Font.Color = vbRed
            End If
        Next
    End If
Next


Set rngData = Nothing

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: This is setting every cell in the range to have a red font color, changing it from black. It is not checking the duplicates.

Comment: @Kish see edit, I forgot to exclude itself when looking for duplicates.

Comment: It works! There is one small issue. When I type in a new cell within the range, it automatically turn red even if there is no, unless I run the macro again then it corrects itself. I would like for it to stay black in the first instance and show up red only when it is a duplicate-- after running the macro

Comment: That is a different question but the quick answer is call this sub from a worksheet change event.

Comment: OK, I will post it separately since I need help with the code.